# What does this golang code do?

Tags: go

I was reading DigitalOcean's golang client. I noticed that they create an instance of their *Op struct in a `_` variable. Example: 
https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/blob/master/droplets.go#L32

```
var _ DropletsService = &DropletsServiceOp{}
```

Why is this line needed?

Comment: @CodingPickle answered this question just before I did, so if you're going to accept an answer, take his/hers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line is a compile time check that [*DropletsServiceOp](https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/blob/2688c11a02dc3deac65645c82c3c812f95e417bf/droplets.go#L28) satisfies the [DropletsService](https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/blob/2688c11a02dc3deac65645c82c3c812f95e417bf/droplets.go#L13-L24) interface.

The line has no effect on the execution of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a neat trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the blame on that file, at that line, you get a clue:

https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/blame/master/droplets.go#L32

It does a compile-time check that `*DropletsServiceOp` satisfies the `DropletsService` interface.  Prior to the commit introducing that, they were doing this in their test suite.